# .htaccess Password protection keeps asking for password over and over

Tags: apache, .htaccess, passwords, password-protection, .htpasswd

I've placed this code in the `.htaccess` file of the folder I want to protect:

```
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/#/#/#/#/#/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

In the same folder, I placed this `.htpasswd`:

```
my:pass
```

When I go to the URL of the protected folder, the browser keeps asking me for a password over and over, even though I'm typing the correct one.

I know that the root directory mentioned in `AuthUserFile` is ok because I've found it out with:

```
<?php
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    echo "<p>Full path to a .htpasswd file in this dir: " . 
        $dir . "/.htpasswd" . "</p>";
?>
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015081/htaccess-doesnt-work-always-wrong-password

Comment: Did you solve this? please add an answer

Comment: Same happened to me so I am reporting here. In my case I was making a server call at the starting of the script which was returning 404 for the first time. Handling that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just add **"user"** in between **require valid-user**

For example:

```
Require user markpanado
```

But not:

```
Require markpanado
```

Comment: you say to add user between require valid-user but your final answer has no valid-user entry... :(

Comment: What if there are two user accounts that need to be allowed in this directory?

Comment: @SpaceDog no, the final answer is the first answer. Read it again.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I haven't tried that, but did you try `Require user1 user2 user3` format?

Comment: @mark The memory is vague but I think that solved my particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

the problem, so i found for my website, is that the htpasswd file path is not the same as the path provided in the htaccess. I spent weeks trying to find where the problem was, but although you create usernames and passes using the htpasswrd the file is not communicating with the secure folder. You will need to find out why. maybe a spelling mistake or as in my case, the htpasswd was being saved in a completely different folder, and i had 2 htpasswrd in different folders. the two need to communicate htacccess and htpasswrd, hope this saves you time I figured it out after weeks of sleepless nights.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this problem. After trying to figure it out for the last couple of days I have found out the source of the problem:

This prompt gets triggered when using AuthType Basic and whenever a 401 message is sent from the website.

Is it possible that you had a 401 HTTP status code message being sent from the server at each request? You can check your developer console to find out.

Comment: I DO see a 401 in my case but when I use a different user I no longer get the prompt repeatedly.

Comment: @Jacksonkr Can you identify which portion of your back-end script is sending the 401 error? Is it a script you created or a platform of some type?

Comment: it's the favicon.ico which seems to be a standard item served out by apache. Furthermore [I filed this as its own question](https://serverfault.com/questions/953631/htaccess-continues-to-prompt-for-password-after-login?noredirect=1#comment1240145_953631) if you're curious to more details.

Comment: this was years ago but yes I'm pretty sure I got 401 back.